# Debugging multithread server in GDB- Find state of every thread. cont and stop while execution

Tags: c++, gdb, pthreads

I attached to my multithread application with gdb and after that type `cont` to continue execution.

- Is there any way to stop execution at any time on `cont` gdb state and check what every thread do?
- How to check state of every thread and get execution line number of each? (commands)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I do, (taken from [here](http://therobotsbrain.blogspot.com.au/2011/02/poor-mans-sampling-profiler-for-live.html) )

Create a little gdb script `stackdumper.gdb` that dumps the stack trace of all threads:

```
thread apply all backtrace
```

Then repeatedly attach gdb and run the dumper:

```
for i in $(seq 1 10) ; do
  gdb -batch -x stackdumper.gdb ./a.out 123456 > stack.$i
  sleep 10
done
```

where `./a.out` is the binary you are interested and 123456 is the PID.

Adjust the sleep to match your sampling needs.

Answer (score 2):

`thread apply all bt`

Or

`info threads`

`t <threadid from above trace >`
Followed by

`where` or `bt`

Answer (score 1):

To get the backtrace for all of the stopped threads type the

```
thread apply all bt
```

command (the output is exactly the same that one might see in the MacOSX crash report box).

Usually the threads are stopped simultaneously in gdb.

Reference: http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/gdb/gdb_40.html

And here's about "all-stop" mode, which is default: http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/All_002dStop-Mode.html

Answer (score 0):

> Is this any way to stop execution at any time on cont gdb state and check what every thread do

If you ask about ways to check what threads do without `gdb` the you can just run 
 `pstask <pid-of-your application>`

Answer (score 0):

Is it "pstack" because i don't think "pstask" is any command in linux, If it is please provide some more info